# SharePoint calendar does not display events

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar

I'm created a calendar view based on an event's list. When I create an event, I am able to see it if I click "view all events" but when I'm in the calendar view, it does not display any of the events.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Thanks, 
Clara

Comment: Is there any filter added on SharePoint Calendar view?

Answer (score 0):

What's the template you use to create "event's list" as you mentioned?

What's the version of SharePoint you used? SharePoint on-premise or SharePoint Online? You can provide some screenshots with us.

Besides, check if you have set some filter in the calendar view settings.

And if you set the correct date rage in the calendar view.